# Catch exception inside asyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jmail

I am facing the issue.
I want to send an email, I make code inside AsyncTask class.
But I can not catch network exception or any exception. Below is my code for sending an email

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void, Object, Void> {
    int count =0;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("user@gmail.com", "password");
        try {
            sender.sendMail("[Quick Hide video]Backup password",
                    "Your backup password is: "+utils.getPassword(),
                    "user@gmail.com",
                    "thienvan.ptit@gmail.com");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Check","check");
            // the code does not run to this with network is not connect
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        // do something
    }
}
```

GMailSender.java

```
public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
...
    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setDataHandler(handler);
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("thien.van","Network Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me to catch exception in Asyntask
Thank you

Comment: Post the error that you are getting

Comment: Probably because you are already catching all exceptions inside the sendMail method.

Comment: Inside Asynctask I could not catch exception... this is my issue

Comment: You cannot be sure that the exception is actually thrown. Turning off the internet might not have to induce the exception to be thrown, the email might be queued and wait for the connection.